# How to draw a line in p5.js using WEBGL

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Does drawing lines in 3D work in p5.js?

The tutorial here: 
https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Getting-started-with-WebGL-in-p5
says that it should, but my attempt just gives a blank page.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400, WEBGL);
}

function draw(){
  line(-100,-100,-100, 100,100,100);
}
```

As Kevin, below, has pointed out, the console gives an error:

```
TypeError: this._renderer.line is not a function
```

when I attempt to use line();

My browser does support WEBGL, if I write draw() as

```
function draw(){
  box();
}
```

a box does indeed get drawn.

The only way I've currently found to draw a line is to write my own function

```
function drawLine(x1, y1, z1, x2,y2, z2){
  beginShape();
  vertex(x1,y1,z1);
  vertex(x2,y2,z2);  
  endShape();
}
```

which does draw a line in 3D space, but the console generates many errors of the form

> Error: WebGL: vertexAttribPointer: -1 is not a valid `index`. This
>   value probably comes from a getAttribLocation() call, where this
>   return value -1 means that the passed name didn't correspond to an
>   active attribute in the specified program.

in so doing, so something must be wrong there as well.

Comment: Does your browser support webgl? Do you get any errors in the console? When I run this code I get an error saying that `this._renderer.line` is not a function.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, yep I get that as well. Have added a bit more detail above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Googling your error](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=p5.js+TypeError:+this._renderer.line+is+not+a+function) returns a ton of results, including [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1638).

So it looks like this is a known issue. The `line()` function is supposed to work, but it hasn't been properly implemented yet.

Googling your second error returns [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1678), which mentions that it might be caused by not setting a `fill()` color before drawing.

Comment: what to do if i have to remove the draw line some parts after few sec

Answer (score -1):

ROFL.

[image]

> If you sit by the river long enough, you will see the body of your enemy float by.

```
https://codepen.io/micrub/pen/rNGXJPJ?editors=0011
```

```
  push();
  fill(255);
  stroke(255);
  line(0, 0, 0, C_ZISE / F, 0, 0);
  pop();

  push();
  fill(255);
  stroke(255);
  line(0, 0, 0, 0, C_ZISE / F, 0);
  pop();
```